# Bypass/disable uppercase -> global inference in Handlebars templates?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars template (fragment):

```
{{#each cbe in abs.XyzBookingEntries}}
    <tr>
        {{#if cbe.isLoaded}}
            <td>{{cbe.XYZdata.ApptDuration}} min:</td> 
            <td>
                {{cbe.XYZdata.ApptType}}
                {{#if cbe.XYZdata.ApptTypeDetailCode}}
                    ({{cbe.XYZdata.ApptTypeDetailCode}})
                {{/if}}
            </td>
            <td {{bindAttr class="cbe.XYZdata.statusClass"}}><strong>{{cbe.XYZdata.ApptStatus}}</strong></td>
        {{else}}
            <td>
                Loading...
            </td>
        {{/if}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

From which you can observe two things:

1. I have capitalized attributes on my model
2. I have inconsistent capitalization in those attributes (XyzBookingEntries vs. XYZdata)

If I weren't using legacy data sources, I'd be glad to fix both these things. But I have multiple underlying data sources with different developers and different conventions (or lack thereof). Models get from my database to the client via mostly-automated ORM and serialization. And since the conventions are not consistent, automated name mapping (say, with `keyForAttributeName`) would be difficult, especially bi-directionally (XYZdata -> xyzdata -> Xyzdata?). But, if it were just a matter of poor conventions I could fix it with documentation.

The bigger problem is that my handlebars template barfs with these names--*I think because it wants to interpret them as globals instead of member attributes*. I get the following warning message when the below template renders:

```
WARNING: Watching an undefined global, Ember expects watched globals to be setup 
by the time the run loop is flushed, check for typos
```

*Though I do get all the data rendered as expected!* And when it is removed from the DOM, I get errors like this:

```
node is undefined
    node.unchain(key, path);
```

If I watch the variables in the call stack when the warnings and errors come up, the keys I'm rendering in the template can be found (in `pendingQueue`, for instance).

The theory that Handlebars thinks they are globals is supported by the fact that if I define the following property:

```
xyzData: function(){
    return this.get('XYZdata');
}.property('XYZdata')
```

and change all my chains to reference `cbe.xyzData.*` instead, the warnings and errors go away!

**So, my question is:**

Is there a way I can configure/convince Ember/Handlebars to work with the attribute names as is, i.e. to ignore the caps -> global convention? I'd like to avoid hand-mapping a large number of attributes if possible. Open to other possibilities/suggestions as well.

I should mention I'm on 1.0.0-pre4, and am seeing the same behavior with a recent master.

Comment: Ancillary information (my question was already long enough): I was experiencing this problem non-chained attribute names as well, but switching from `{{#each myArray}}...{{this.Attribute}}` to `{{#each item in myArray}}...{{item.Attribute}}` skirted the problem. Once I got to using a chained property path though, it stopped helping. Also, I could workaround the problem somewhat by switching `{{cbe.XYZdata.ApptType}}` to `{{unbound cbe.XYZdata.ApptType}}`. So the problem seems to lie in creating the bound regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can configure/convince Ember/Handlebars to work with the attribute names as is, i.e. to ignore the caps -> global convention?

These conventions are baked-in to the framework pretty deeply, for sure there is no on/off switch.

> I'd like to avoid hand-mapping a large number of attributes if possible. Open to other possibilities/suggestions as well.

This is exactly what serializer is for. Sure hand-mapping these attributes sounds like a big lift but unless you're data sources are changing daily it's a one-time thing, and not much more effort than it will take to define the ember-objects in the first place. Another benefit is that you'd encapsulate this mapping in one place, freeing your ember modesl/controllers/views/templates to work with a consistent naming convention. I would seriously recommend investing in this approach. For example:

```
serializer.map(Cbe, {
  xyzdata: { key: 'XYZdata' }
});
```

With these in place ember will take care of bi-directional mapping for all of your attributes. Have a look at the [json serializer tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/json_serializer_test.js) for more examples of how this might be done.

Comment: Hmm...thanks, and this may be the answer, but what a pain. I have about 150 attributes+relationships in my model layer so far and I think I've built out about 1-2% of my domain. At least perhaps I can combine automated mapping in the serializer with manual maps for the exceptions--does that sound plausible? 

The other irritating thing about this solution is that I already feel like I'm duplicating the definitions for my models in the client and server, and this would be a *third* place I'd have to define all my properties. Doesn't feel very DRY.

Comment: Appears to be the case, though I still consider this a bug...I understand it's supposed to treat something that _starts_ with a capital, but treating `cbe.XYZdata.statusClass` because the _second_ segment in the path is capitalized doesn't make sense--especially when it _doesn't_ treat `abs.XyzBookingEntries` as a global.

Comment: Incidentally, I was able to make a rule-based mapping function (by defining `DS.Serializer.keyForAttributeName(...)` and only explicitly map the exceptions. So at least I didn't have to hand-map everything.

Comment: Nice! If you have time maybe post about that somewhere, seems like other people with lots of models could benefit from the approach.