# Ember- live preview image

Tags: ember.js, live-preview

I'm doing a product form with a live preview just for fun

HBS

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <label>Product name: </label>
        {{input type="text" placeholder="First name" value=newProductname class="form-control"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <label>Price: </label>
        {{input type="text" placeholder="$$" value=price class="form-control"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <label>Image location: </label>
        {{input type="text" placeholder="Url" value=Url class="form-control"}}
    </div>
```

And this live preview would come up simply using their values in  {{ }}

```
<h1>{{newProductname}}</h1>
<p>{{price}}$</p>
<p>{{description}}<p>
<img {{bind-attr src="need Url value here"}}></img>
```

So how would you do this nested binding or simply recommend another solution?

cheers

Kristjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Ember doesn't like uppercase properties, I'll look into it.  For now use a lowercase property name.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <label>Image location: </label>
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Url" value=url class="form-control"}}
</div>

<img {{bind-attr src=url}}>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/idUWEGU/2/edit

### Update:

Looks related to a global namespace, apparently an uppercase property infers global namespace [Bypass/disable uppercase -> global inference in Handlebars templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702224/bypass-disable-uppercase-global-inference-in-handlebars-templates)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/idUWEGU/1/edit

### Other update:

You can always define the scope by qualifying your binding more.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <label>Image location: </label>
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Url" value=controller.Url class="form-control"}}
</div>
<img {{bind-attr src=controller.Url}}>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/idUWEGU/3/edit